# Can the Visual State Manager in WPF 4 swap out control templates / styles?

Tags: wpf, .net-4.0, visualstatemanager

I can't seem to find a definitive answer for this so I thought it might help others looking to just ask the question. Can the VSM be used to swap out templates.

As an example, If I have a user control with a content presenter on it can I use the VSM of the user control to move between two different templates for content presenter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this is an incorrect way to use the VSM. The idea is to define all of your states in a single template. You can then move, collapse or hide various parts of the template based on VSM States. The nice thing about this is that you don't need multiple templates, a single template becomes self contained for all the various states of your ViewModel.

TL;DR use one template for VSM, define all your states in this template and then use GoToState to hide or show various parts.

Comment: Thanks for your direct answer. I learned to look for concise nuggets of wisdom like this after my initial horrible experience with WPF ControlTemplates. Like many developers I just wasn't willing to accept that Microsoft would have designed it so that you have to copy a whole control template to make one simple modification but a firm and direct answer such as yours on the topic of VSM could have saved me a lot of time then.